# array_push method not working

Tags: php

I am creating one web service in this web service I need two array result in one array. One array come through out database and second array come for calculation part so this two array I want to need under one array

My code is:

```
<?php
$jsonData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);

include 'connection.php';

$pc_name        = $_POST["pc_name"];
$total_hours    = $_POST["total_hours"];
$base_fare      = $_POST["base_fare"];
$start_date     = $_POST["start_date"];
$start_month    = date("M", strtotime($start_date));
$end_date       = $_POST["end_date"];
$end_month      = date("M", strtotime($end_date));
$weekday_status = $_POST["weekday_status"];
$v_model        = $_POST["v_model"];
$day_status     = $_POST["day_status"];
$date           = date("m/d/Y");
//print_r("select * from tbl_promocode where promocode='$pc_name'");  die();
  $sql      = "select * from tbl_promocode where promocode='$pc_name'";
  $stmt     = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
  $checkrow = sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt);
  if($checkrow>0)
   {
     while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
     {
         $cat_type = $row['cat_type'];
         $end_date = $row['end_date'];
     }
     if($date>$end_date)
       {
           $response["response"]="Offer is expired";
       }
       else
       {
           if($cat_type==1)
             {
                $sql1       = "select * from tbl_promocode where cat_type='1' and promocode='$pc_name'";
                $stmt1      = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql1);
                while($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
                 {  
                     $result = $row1;
                 } 
                 $response["response"]="success";
                 $response["result"]=$result;               
             }
             else if($cat_type==2)
             {
                 if($total_hours>=4)
                 {
                    $sql2       = "select * from tbl_promocode where cat_type='2' and promocode='$pc_name'";
                    $stmt2      = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql2);
                    while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
                    {  
                      $result2 = $row2;
                    } 
                    $response["response"]="success";
                    $response["result"]=$result2; 
                 }
                                  else
                 {
                     $response["response"]="Invalid Promocode";
                 }
             }
             else if($cat_type==3)
             {
                if($total_hours>=48)
                 {
                    $sql3       = "select * from tbl_promocode where cat_type='3' and promocode='$pc_name'";
                    $stmt3      = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql3);
                    while($row3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
                    {  
                      $result3 = $row3;
                    } 
                    $response["response"]="success";
                    $response["result"]=$result3; 
                 }  
                                 else
                 {
                     $response["response"]="Invalid Promocode";
                 }
             }
             else if($cat_type==4)
             {
                if($base_fare>=5000)
                {
                    $sql4       = "select * from tbl_promocode where cat_type='4' and promocode='$pc_name'";
                    $stmt4      = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql4);
                    while($row4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt4, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
                    {  
                      $result4 = $row4;
                    } 
                    $response["response"]="success";
                    $response["result"]=$result4;   
                }
                             else
                 {
                     $response["response"]="Invalid Promocode";
                 }
             } 
             else if($cat_type==5)
             {
                    $sql5       = "select * from tbl_promocode where cat_type='5' and promocode='$pc_name'";
                    $stmt5      = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql5);
                    while($row5 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt5, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
                    {  
                      $result5 = $row5;
                    } 
                    $amount      = 10/100*$base_fare;
                    $response["response"]="success";
                    $response["result"]=$result5; 
                    $response1["cal_amount"]=$amount;
                    array_push($response,$response1);
             }
             else if($cat_type==6)
             {
                    $sql6       = "select * from tbl_promocode where cat_type='6' and promocode='$pc_name'";
                    $stmt6      = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql6);
                    while($row6 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt6, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
                    {  
                      $result6 = $row6;
                    } 
                    $amount      = 20/100*$base_fare;
                    $response["response"]="success";
                    $response["result"]=$result6;
                    $response1["cal_amount"]=$amount; 
                    array_push($response,$response1); 
             }
             else if($cat_type==7)
             {
                    $sql7       = "select * from tbl_promocode where cat_type='7' and promocode='$pc_name'";
                    $stmt7      = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql7);
                    while($row7 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt7, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
                    {  
                      $result7 = $row7;
                    } 
                    $amount      = 30/100*$base_fare;
                    $response["response"]="success";
                    $response["result"]=$result7; 
                    $response1["cal_amount"]=$amount;
                    array_push($response,$response1);
             }
             else if($cat_type==8)
             {
                    $sql8       = "select * from tbl_promocode where cat_type='8' and promocode='$pc_name'";
                    $stmt8      = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql8);
                    while($row8 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt8, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
                    {  
                      $result8 = $row8;
                    } 
                    $amount      = 50/100*$base_fare;
                    $response["response"]="success";
                    $response["result"]=$result8;
                    $response1["cal_amount"]=$amount;
                    array_push($response,$response1); 
             }
             else if($cat_type==9)
             {
                    $sql9       = "select * from tbl_promocode where cat_type='9' and promocode='$pc_name'";
                    $stmt9      = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql9);
                    while($row9 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt9, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
                    {  
                      $result9 = $row9;
                    } 
                    $amount      = 10/100*$base_fare;
                    $response["response"]="success";
                    $response["result"]=$result9;
                    $response1["cal_amount"]=$amount;                   
                   array_push($response,$response1);
             }
             else
             {
                 $response["response"]="Invalid Promocode";
             }
        }
    }
else
    {
         $response["response"]="Invalid Promocode";
    }
die(json_encode($response));
?>

my result is:-

{
  "0": {
    "cal_amount": 500
  },
  "response": "success",
  "result": {
    "id": 6,
    "promocode_name": "TRIP10",
    "start_date": {
      "date": "2017-03-20 00:00:00.000000",
      "timezone_type": 3,
      "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "end_date": {
      "date": "2017-05-31 00:00:00.000000",
      "timezone_type": 3,
      "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "promocode": "TRIP10",
    "amount": "empty",
    "amount_type": "empty",
    "status": "active",
    "Cancel_Flag": 0,
    "cat_type": 5,
    "percentage": "10",
    "v_model": "empty",
    "off_month": "empty"
  }
}
```

Using this web service my data is right one but problem is that in result set to starting zero printing. I want to remove this zero or converted to any string. So what I do to solve this problem please help me anyone

Comment: Please reduce that wall of code to a minimal example demonstrating your issue. Thanks.

Comment: I can tell there is a language barrier but can you show example output of what you are getting and what you expect? As is I cannot understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

here I think you need to replace

```
 array_push($response,$response1);
```

with

```
$response = array_merge($response,$response1);
```

because array_push() is used to append an element to array while you are append an array to it.
so if here if gonna use array_push() then you have to loop through all the elements of one array and adding it to another through array_push() one by one.
so for that better to use array_merge() instead.